# Not able to scrape the image urls properly using selenium, beautiufulsoup and python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Link that I am scraping : https://www.indusind.com/in/en/personal/cards/credit-card.html

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json, requests, re, sys
from selenium import webdriver
import re, time

IndusInd_url = "https://www.indusind.com/in/en/personal/cards/credit-card.html"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\Hari\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(IndusInd_url)
time.sleep(3)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

img = []
for x in soup.find_all('img'):
    if ".jpg" and "creditCard" in x.get('src'):
        img.append("https://www.indusind.com"+x.get('src'))

print(len(img))
print(img)
driver.close()
```

Using the above code I am scraping the image urls from the above link

**Output**

```
21
['https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/crest_world_elite.jpg', 'https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/indulge_credit_card.jpg', 'https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/celesta-credit-card.jpg', 'https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/indulge_credit_card.jpg', 'https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/crest_world_elite.jpg', 'https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/celesta-credit-card.jpg', 'https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/th-pioneer-heritage-credit-card.png', 'https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/pioneer_legacy_world_card.jpg', 'https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/pinnacle_master-card.jpg', 'https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/Legend_card-image_396x257px.png', 'https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/nexxt-credit-card.jpg', 'https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/platinum_select.jpg', 'https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/payback-visa-credit-card.jpg', 'https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/iconia_-card_american_express.jpg', 'https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/iconia-visa-credit-card.jpg', 'https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/intermiles-card_Odyssey_amex_front.png', 'https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/intermiles-odyssey-visa-credit-card.jpg', 'https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/intermiles-card_Voyage_amex_front.png', 'https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/intermiles-voyage-visa-credit-card.jpg', 'https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/signature_card.jpg', 'https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/platinum_aura_master.jpg']
```

The output to some extent is correct, but many of the image urls in that list are repetitive, and the links are not in order with respect to the cards in the website, and there are a total of 22 cards, so in the output I want the 22 image urls in the list in order w.r.t to the website.

I'd like to know an alternative code that could solve all the issues with the output.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are just searching for `jpg` but there are some `png` images as well.

Also, there are three repetitions due to the three images in the main section. You can skip the first three (`n`) based on count of `set` and `list` with slicing.

Further, you can directly get the images using the selector `rounded-1 w-100` and getting rid of `if` conditions:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json, requests, re, sys
from selenium import webdriver
import re, time

IndusInd_url = "https://www.indusind.com/in/en/personal/cards/credit-card.html"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\I346696\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(IndusInd_url)
time.sleep(3)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

img = []
for x in soup.find_all('img', class_ = 'rounded-1 w-100'):
    img.append("https://www.indusind.com" + x.get('src'))

start = len(img) - len(set(img))
img = img[start:]
print(len(img))
for im in img:
    print(im)

driver.close()
```

Output:

```
22
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/indulge_credit_card.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/crest_world_elite.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/celesta-credit-card.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/th-pioneer-heritage-credit-card.png
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/pioneer_legacy_world_card.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/pinnacle_master-card.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/Legend_card-image_396x257px.png
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/nexxt-credit-card.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/product/creditcardimages/Platinum396x257px.png
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/platinum_select.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/product/creditcardimages/AuraEdge396x257px.png
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/payback-visa-credit-card.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/iconia_-card_american_express.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/iconia-visa-credit-card.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/intermiles-card_Odyssey_amex_front.png
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/intermiles-odyssey-visa-credit-card.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/intermiles-card_Voyage_amex_front.png
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/intermiles-voyage-visa-credit-card.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/signature_card.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/platinum_aura_master.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/debitCard/duo-card_Visa_front.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/banner-images/iconia-amex-visa/card-stack.png
```

You could also just convert the list to set if you don't want the ordering preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Those duplicated image source urls are coming from the recommended section. So you need to skip those first three items and then you'll have all the image links in the right order.

Here's how:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.indusind.com/in/en/personal/cards/credit-card.html")
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.chkboxcard .cat-card-header img')
cards = [element.get_attribute("src") for element in elements][3:]

print(len(cards))

for card in cards:
    print(card)
```

Output:

```
22
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/indulge_credit_card.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/crest_world_elite.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/celesta-credit-card.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/th-pioneer-heritage-credit-card.png
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/pioneer_legacy_world_card.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/pinnacle_master-card.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/Legend_card-image_396x257px.png
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/nexxt-credit-card.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/product/creditcardimages/Platinum396x257px.png
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/platinum_select.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/product/creditcardimages/AuraEdge396x257px.png
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/payback-visa-credit-card.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/iconia_-card_american_express.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/iconia-visa-credit-card.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/intermiles-card_Odyssey_amex_front.png
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/intermiles-odyssey-visa-credit-card.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/intermiles-card_Voyage_amex_front.png
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/intermiles-voyage-visa-credit-card.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/signature_card.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/creditCard/platinum_aura_master.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/productCategory/desktopImage/debitCard/duo-card_Visa_front.jpg
https://www.indusind.com/content/dam/indusind-platform-images/banner-images/iconia-amex-visa/card-stack.png
```